# Second order theories and models (based on ZFC)

Tags: set-theory

In the context of ZFC we say that almost any mathematical structure one can imagine exists as a set in ZFC. That is his role as foundations.

But from another perspective,it is not true in general that any (provably) consistent second order theory has a model.

On another twist, a lot of mathematical structures of interest are unequivocally defined (up to isomorphism) in second order statements (natural numbers, rational, reals,...). This particular theories have a model.

Does it mean that:

Some consistent second order theories are not mathematics at all

Or that the "almost all" accounts for the posible existence of mathematical structures of interest based on second order theories that doesn't have a model.

Is there some example of the latter?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "consistent" for a second order theory?

Comment: That I cannot prove $\phi$ and  $\neg \phi$ using the deductive system.

Comment: @Eduard There's no complete deductive system for second-order logic, so you need to clarify what you mean by "the deductive system".

Comment: Ahhh... didn't know. I would say the same deductive system as the first order. Mòdul ponens, generalization...

Comment: Which are the standard options for a deductive system for second order logic?

Comment: I was thinking about the same first order deductive system but allowing second order sentences as non logical axioms... Not sure if it makes sense. The reals has no deductive system at all? The only definition of consistency is the fact they have a model?

Comment: I would try to write it differently. I can describe reals as a complete archimedian ordered field. This requeriments can be expressed using second order expressions within the language (of set theory?). Within set theory as metatheory we can prove that exists a set with this characteristics. Now, the question, if I change the requirements, using other second order expressions, I would be able to find a set that fulfills the requirements?

Comment: I think I don't know at all what it means second order...

Comment: The dedekind complete statement is second order because it range over sets, not only over elements. But in set theory every thing is a set, so it is a first order statement...

Comment: @Eduard I may be wrong, but using a function $\mathbb R\to\mathcal P(\mathbb Q)$ can we encode the statement "each real generates a unique Dedekind cut" in a first-order way in terms of reals only, where the latter real codes a set of rationals via that function?